# Getting Letters of recommedation with no professor suport

Tags: recommendation-letter

How does one obtain letters of rec after he/she graduated from university?

I am currently enrolled in a  post-bac biotechnology program where I could identity one potential candidate for a letter. I have one letter from my former boss where I dealt with computers. But what are my options getting another letter? BTW I haven't known my professor in the biotechnology program forever (just 2 months). How long do you have to know a professor before asking?

Comment: Thanks! I always thought it was impossible to get letters after college. I have been struggling to get them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I haven't known my professor in the biotechnology program forever (just 2 months). How long do you have to know a professor before asking?

There is no stipulated time duration. It is just that the person writing that recommendation letter has to well acquainted with your work, to feel confident while endorsing you. In your case, the relevant points would be how well you fared in any self-learning modules of his course, or otherwise, in his course in general. (I'm assuming there's no "*project*" type thing involved. If there is, even better!, because that gives him a better opportunity to judge your potential.)

So, if you feel he has had ample exposure to your work to be in a position to write a favorable recommendation letter for you, you should absolutely go ahead!

> How does one obtain letters of rec after he/she graduated from university?

Provided the above stipulation is satisfied, you can go and meet him personally, or even write an email if the former is not possible. You haven't mentioned for how long have you haven't been in touch with him in the question. If it is 1-2 years, it is likely that he wouldn't have completely forgotten you, or at least, you can ring up old memories in any case. Also, you must absolutely enclose your CV in the email.

Please bear in mind that if he doesn't feel confident enough, or has his doubts, he is most likely not going to respond to your email, and obviously, no recommendation also. If your entire correspondence is via email only, you could send him one, or at most, two gentle reminders, but DO NOT press it beyond that! Also, space the reminders by about a week or so. If he doesn't reply, accept it calmly that this avenue is gone. If it is gone, you will have to look for another guy, but all this is definitely worth a shot. I mean, you have nothing to lose.

Hope that helps :)